# Delete multiple file for/while

Tags: php

I have a php pull down that I select an item and delete
all files associated with it.

It works well if there was only 5 or 6. After I put the
first 4 to test and get it working I realized it could
take a very long time to enter in a couple hundred and
would blot the script.

Not knowing enough about for and while loops is there
anyone that might have a way to help?

There will never be more than one set deleted at a time.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$workitem = $_POST["workitem"];
$workdirPAth = "/var/work.files/";


if($workitem == 'item1.php')
{
  unlink("$workdirPath/page1.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/temp1.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/all1.php");
}
if($workitem == 'item2.php')
{
  unlink("$workdirPath/page2.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/temp2.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/all2.php");
}
if($workitem == 'item3.php')
{
  unlink("$workdirPath/page3.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/temp3.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/all3.php");
}
if($workitem == 'item4.php')
{
  unlink("$workdirPath/page4.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/temp4.php");
  unlink("$workdirPath/all3.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple pattern matching and substitution is all you need here.

First, the code:

```
   1.   if (preg_match('/^item(\d+)\.php$/', $workitem, $matches)) {
   2.     $number = $matches[1];
   3.     foreach(array('page','temp','all') as $base) {
   4.       unlink("$workdirPath/$base$number.php");
   5.     }
   6.   } else {
   7.     # unrecognized work item value; complain to user or whatever
   8.   }
```

The `preg_match` function takes a pattern, a string, and an array.  If the string matches the pattern, the parts that match are stored in the array.  The particular type of pattern is a *p*erl5-compatible *reg*ular expression, which is where the `preg_` part of the name comes from.

Regular expressions are scary-looking to the uninitiated, but they're a handy way to scan a string and get some values out of it. Most characters just represent themselves; the string `"foo"` matches the regular expression `/foo/`.  But some characters have special meanings that let you make more general patterns to match a whole set of strings where you don't have to know ahead of time exactly what's in them.

The `/`s just mark the beginning and end of the actual regular expression; they're there because you can stick additional modifier flags inside the string along with the expression itself.

The `^`and `$` arepresent the beginning and end of the string. `"/foo/"` matches `"foo"`, but also `"foobar"`, `"bunnyfoofoo"`, and so on - any string that *contains* "foo" will match.  But `/^foo$/` matches only "`foo"` exactly.

`\d` means "any digit".  `+` means "one or more of that last thing".  So `\d+` means "one or more digits".

The period (`.`) is special; it matches any character at all.  Since we want a literal period, we have to escape it with a backslash; `\.` just matches a period.

So our regular expression is `'/^item\d+\.php$/'`, which will match any `item`*number*`.php` filename.  But that's not quite enough.  The `preg_match` function is basically a binary test: does the string match the pattern or not, yes or no?  In this case, it's not enough to just say "yup, the string is valid"; we need to know *which* items specifically the user specified.  That's what capture groups are for.  We use parentheses to say "remember what matched this part", and provide an array name that gets filled with those remembrances.

The part of the string that matches the whole regular expression (which may not be the whole string, if the regular expression isn't anchored with `^`...`$` like this one is) is always put in element 0 of the array.  If you use parentheses in the regular expression, then the part of the string that matches the part of the regular expression inside the first pair of parentheses is stored in element 1 of the array; if there's a second set of parentheses, the matching part of the string goes in element 2 of the array, and so on.

So we put parentheses around our number (`(\d+)`) and then the actual number will be remembered in element 1 of our `$matches` array.

Great, we have a number. Now we just need to use it to build up the filenames we want to delete.

In each case, we want to delete three files: `page$n.php`, `temp$n.php`, and `all$n.php`, where `$n` is the number we extracted above.  We could just put three `unlink` calls, but since they're all so similar, we can use a loop instead.

Take the different prefixes that are the same no matter the number, and make an array out of them.  Then loop over that array.  In the body of the loop, the variable `$base` will contain whichever element of the array it's currently on.  Stick that between the `$workdirPath` prefix and the `$number` we got from the match, append `.php`, and that's your file.  `unlink` it and go back to the top of the loop to grab the next one.

Comment: Wow!, I'll copy all this and put in my reading material. Worked plain and simple. Thank you so much.